# Is Picture in Picture possible on IOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, picture-in-picture

I'm Trying to use Picture in Picture on IOS Simulator (Iphone 11 - IOS 14.5) but I can't do it, I've tested on youtube, vimeo and raw videos but nothing happens. I've also tried to enable PIP on settings but I couldn't find the option there, maybe it's limited on the simulator?

[image]

Comment: Also trying to find an answer to this question.  From what I can see `AVPictureInPictureController.isPictureInPictureSupported()` always returns false on the simulator, before during and after successfully playing a video.

Comment: Interestingly PiP _is_ available on __iPad__ simulators and works as expected.  Maybe an iPhone simulator-only issue/oversight from Apple?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently (Q2 2022) it seems that Picture-in-Picture is omitted from simulated iPhones, even when the model of iPhone in question supports PIP on real hardware.

However, as [Robin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68939003/is-picture-in-picture-possible-on-ios-simulator/72326067#comment122853678_68939003) pointed out, PIP *is* available on simulated iPads such as the iPad Pro (9.7-inch).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that on the simulator, you don't have the option to enable/disable the picture-in-picture option. It just works.

Comment: What’s the implication there, Sufian?

Comment: That any other non-iOS user doesn't check the availability of the PIP feature by going to Settings > General as it is only available on real iOS devices. I (primarily an Android and React Native developer) wasted mine by downloading different iOS versions and only checking the settings.